# How to slideout and destroy in extjs4 panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How to slide out a panel and then close?

i tried like this but it doesn't remove the panel, it just seems to be hiding

```
this.el.slideOut('b', {remove: true});
```

in the panel configuration i have this

```
closable: true,
closeAction: 'destroy',
```

what i want to do is slideout panel then close it. any idea why this doesn't remove panel from DOM ?

Regards

Comment: I have   doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code.Hope it will help you:

```
var btn = Ext.create('Ext.Button',{
  text    : 'hide me',
  handler : function() {
    myPanel.el.switchOff({
      callback : function() {
          myPanel.el.slideOut('b',{remove : true});
           myPanel.destroy();
      }
    });
  } 
});

myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
  width    : 200,
  height   : 100,
  title    : 'Title me',
  frame    : true,
  renderTo : Ext.getBody(), 
  items    :  btn   
});
```

You can check the working sample using below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/kesamkiran/kVbra/14/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but seems like this also not destroy panel :(

Comment: Sorry i am not understanding your problem.For destroying only we are using myPanel.destroy(); in button handler.Still if you face problem let us know in detail.

Comment: sorry for my explanations. i mean by destroy is remove panel completely from DOM

Comment: check this out first hide then click clickme button and there is still panel exist though  http://jsfiddle.net/DXXJu/1/